# Bash, how to calculate total from loop output

Tags: bash, loops

Please assist on that matter, I am trying to get a total number from loop that outputs 4 numbers as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
Bank=4
for ((out=1; out<=$Bank; out++)) do
        echo $out
done
```

I am getting output that looks like that:

```
1
2
3
4
```

How can I calculate `1+2+3+4` and get that calculated output `10` instead of `1 2 3 4`?
Originally variables `1 2 3 4` will be different like `585 430 170 64`, can't figure out where to put `| bc -l`. Thanks!

Comment: Add to your loop: `sum=$(($sum+$out))` and output `$sum` after your loop.

Comment: This option is very helpful as well, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where to put | bc -l

After the loop.

```
for ....
  ...
done | paste -sd+ | bc -l
```